# How can I highlight on mouse click selected row of the table using Bootstrap 4 and Angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular6

I have a Bootstrap table using table-hover and everything works properly `.table-hover` enables a hover state on table rows within a `<tbody>`. I also have this method:

```
listClick(event, newValue) {
    this.UploaderService.getFileName(newValue[1])
}
```

which sets name of the file from the specified row and then other methods from 
`UploaderService` uses this variable to execute specified operations like deleting, uploading etc.

My problem is that everything works fine, unfortunately the line being clicked is not highlighted so the user is not completely aware of the selected row. I would like to leave this line highlighted at the moment of clicking a specific action on this object, such as deleting etc.

Furthermore I would like to have a possibility to select multiple rows using combination for instance of mouse clicking + cmd in case of mac os. Any ideas how can I do this?

```
<div style="display: block;" class="table-div content table-responsive table-full-width"  >
   <table class="Table table table-hover">
     <div>
     <thead >
     <tr >
       <th style="width: 20vw; min-width: 150px; text-align: left " *ngFor="let cell of this.UploaderService.tableData2.headerRow">{{ cell }}</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     </div>
     <tbody style="  overflow:auto; height:60vh; margin-bottom:1vh; display: block; left: 0vw; right: 0vw">

         <tr *ngFor="let item of this.UploaderService.uploader.queue">
           <td><button type="button" (click)="item.remove()">Cancel</button>
                                             <div class="progress">
                       <div class="progress-bar bg-success"
                       [ngStyle]="{'width':item.progress+'%'}"></div>
                   </div>
           </td>
           <td>
           <div >{{item.file.name}}</div>
         </td>
           <td>
             <div >{{item.file.size}}</div>
           </td>
           <td>
           <div >{{item.file.type}}</div>
           </td>
           <td>
             <div >{{item.file.lastModifiedDate}}</div>
           </td>
     <tr *ngFor="let row of this.UploaderService.tableData2.dataRows">
       <td [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem == cell}" (click)="listClick($event, row)" (dblclick)="listDoubleClick($event, row)"  style="cursor: pointer; width: 20vw; min-width: 150px; text-align: left" *ngFor="let cell of dateFormat(row)">{{cell}}</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

I try like this:

ts:

```
listClick(event, row) {

    row.isSelected = !row.isSelected;
    this.UploaderService.getFileName(row[1])

  }
```

html:

```
            <tr *ngFor="let row of this.UploaderService.tableData2.dataRows">


              <td [ngClass]="{'active': row.isSelected}" (click)="listClick($event, row)" (dblclick)="listDoubleClick($event, row)"  style="cursor: pointer; width: 20vw; min-width: 150px; text-align: left" *ngFor="let cell of dateFormat(row)">{{cell}}</td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is just to add one attribute like: 
`isSelected: boolean` to you dataRows when one or more of them is selected;

```
listClick(event, newValue, cell) {
    cell.isSelected = !cell.isSelected;
    this.UploaderService.getFileName(newValue[1])
}
```

but i highly recommend you to use this excellent data table in angular
[ngxDataTable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable)

hope it help.

Comment: if you have any problem or can not solve it, please run you code here https://stackblitz.com/ i'll do my best to help you.

Comment: Do you mean `(click)="listClick($event, row)` and `listClick(event, row) {

    row.isSelected = !row.isSelected;
    this.UploaderService.getFileName(row[1])

}`?

Comment: @thedbogh yes, exactly :)
[ngClass]="{'active': row.isSelected}"

Comment: I added part of this source code to the question. Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem was with css, I forgot to add for instance `.active{ background-color: yellow; } ` Furthermore, when I click specified row it is highlighted what is okay, but when I click another one they are both highlighted but I would like to remove highlighting from the previous one. Any ideas?

Comment: @thedbogh
this solution works well for multiple selection, for single selection just declare one variable list **public selectedRow: any;** then assign the row in listClick function to this variable, after that in html just put this variable in front of css Class.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 5 you need to use bootstrap class "table-active".

html:

```html
 <tr [class.table-active]="i == currentRowIndex" *ngFor="let row of this.UploaderService.tableData2.dataRows; let i = index" (click)="onRowClick(i)">
```

ts:

```js
currentRowIndex: number = -1;

onRowClick(index: number) {
  this.currentRowIndex = index;
}
```